# Do airplanes have any kind of fire insulation?

Tags: aircraft-design, airliner, fire

Commercial airplanes sometimes suffer from a bird strike or something else that could ignite a part of the engine. So apart from noise insulation, do airliners have fire insulation?

Comment: As well the APU comparment is protected agaisnt fire

Comment: Yes. As you could have found in seconds by searching for "aircraft fire insulation" with your favourite search engine.

Comment: Are you asking about the engines or the fuselage?

Comment: @TomMcW About anything that could serve as fire insulation

Comment: @DavidRicherby I could be wrong, but isn't the goal of the SE network to build a canonical set of questions and answers?  Something being searchable, even easily searchable, doesn't necessarily make it a bad question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, aircraft have fire-protection systems as well with many of the materials being of such a sort.

From [boeing.com](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/2011_q4/4/) about the fire-resistant/fire-suppression systems on their aircraft. You can see that most of the aircraft is covered in these materials. Emphasis mine.

> Interior components of Boeing airplanes meet flammability requirements prescribed in Title 14 Code of Federal Regulations (CFR) Part 25. These components include:
>
> ```
> - Interior ceiling.
> - Interior sidewall panels.
> - Partitions.
> - Galley surfaces and structure.
> - Exposed surfaces of stowed galley carts and standard galley containers.
> - Large cabinets and cabin stowage compartments.
> - Passenger seat material.
> ```
>
> For materials in areas not covered by the CFR requirements, Boeing design guidelines are used to identify additional flammability, smoke, and toxicity requirements.
>   The standards for flammability of insulation blankets have improved over time. A recent requirement change calls for the enhancement of the fire-protective features of **insulation blankets** in the event of an in-flight or post-crash fire. The latest standard increases protection by minimizing the contribution of the insulation blankets to the propagation of a fire. **Thermal/acoustic insulation** installed behind cabin interior panels with the appropriate fire-resistant properties can delay the onset of fire into the cabin in the event of a crash (see fig. 1). ***The insulation blankets, along with the airplane skin, must be capable of resisting burn-through from a fuel-fed post-crash fire next to the bottom half of the fuselage for a minimum of four minutes to allow passengers to evacuate the airplane before burn-through can occur.***

You can also find out much more in that webpage about the various active and passive fire-suppression systems in aircraft.

The FAA Regulation about these systems can be found [here](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aircraft/amt_airframe_handbook/media/ama_Ch17.pdf) in PDF format.